# | as pattern when using split

Tags: c#, regex

```
string input = @"12.2.2010|7";   
string pattern = @"|";

foreach (string result in Regex.Split(input, pattern)) 
{
   Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", result);
}
```

i want to use | as patter but becouse | means or i can't get 12.2.2010. How can i use | like pattern? I try to use ~ but is the same.

Comment: Why use a `Regex` if all you want is to split on a single character?  `input.Split('|')` would work just fine here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character `|` has a special meaning in a regular expression, which means you have to escape it with a `\` like so:

```
string pattern = @"\|";
```

Check out the following website for some more information: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 5):

Try to escape the `|` like this

```
string pattern = @"\|";
```

Answer (score 3):

In a regular expression, if you want to match a literal |, you need to escape it with a backslash, like so:

```
string pattern = @"\|";
```